# Multivariable limit with min and max

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

1) I'm trying to show that 
$$
\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0, 0)} \frac{\max(x,y)}{\min(x,y)} = 1.
$$
I'm not totally sure the limit exists, but I couldn't find a counterexample so far.
I've tried the squeeze theorem, since the limit is $\ge 1$, but I haven't found a way showing it's $\le 1$.

2) I wonder if it also holds for a more general (finite) case, where the number of variables is $N > 2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the limit exists, it must be the same on all paths to the origin.

Suppose $x = 2y$

Approaching from the right we would have $\lim_\limits{y\to 0}\frac {2y}{y} = 2$

Approaching from the left we have $\frac {y}{2y} = \frac 12$

And choosing a different path we would get a different evaluation.

The limit does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

For $0<x<1$ and $y=x^{2}$, then $\max(x,y)=x$ and $\min(x,y)=x^{2}$, so we have $\dfrac{x}{x^{2}}=\dfrac{1}{x}\rightarrow\infty$ as $x\rightarrow 0^{+}$.